# moment-timezone parsing the given time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have an issue when parsing the Date object using the moment-timezone

### The problem

I am creating a nodejs app that should check the new Date() object with arbitrary time from database (and act accordingly). The time, and the timezone are persisted in database.

In example

```
time | timezone
11:00| US/Eastern
```

When a REST call comes, I have to take new Date() object and to transform it to given timezone and see whether the current time is later than 9am. But servers timezone and persisted timezone are not the same.

### The issue

I create todays date string like this

```
function getTodaysDate() {
    var today = new Date(),
        dd = today.getDate(),
        mm = today.getMonth()+1,
        yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    }

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    }
    
    return yyyy +'-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    
}
```

And trying to create Timestamp object with moment-timezone

```
startTime = moment.tz(new Date(getTodaysDate() + ' ' + '11:00'), 'US/Eastern');
```

But the framework correctly takes the date and **transforms** it to US/Eastern time zone.

So when I print startTime.format();

I get

```
2016-08-01T07:00:00-04:00
```

And I would like

```
2016-08-01T11:00:00-04:00
```

So is there a way using moment-timezone package to set the Date and time and to just treat them as given timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that

```
startTime = moment.tz('here the date goes', 'US/Eastern');
```

Was either expecting ISO format or manually formatted (syntax of this was not known to me), or the Date() object. I first tried with  this

```
2016-08-01 11:00
```

Moment library complained (I will post the full error message when I come to office).

### Solution

Add T.

```
startTime = moment.tz('2016-08-01T11:00', 'US/Eastern');
```

I hate timedate libraries and how we track of time.

Comment: Moment will accept the input in iso format with or without the `T` separator.  If you had a custom format, you could supply it with format tokens in between your two existing parameters.

Comment: It accepted the format but it printed "soon to be deprecated" errors. I did not know about format  - now I know :)

Comment: See the list in the docs under "Supported ISO 8601 strings" [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).  You won't get the deprecation message if your input format is one of those listed.  If it's anything else, then use the [string + format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) approach instead.  It works the same with `moment.tz` also.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of the `Date` object manipulation.  In theory, you should just be able to do:

```
var zone = 'US/Eastern'
var time = '11:00'

var result = moment.tz(time, 'HH:mm', zone).format();
```

However, there's [a known bug](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/119) with this that uses the UTC current date instead of the time zone's current date. Until it's fixed, you have to do this instead:

```
var zone = 'US/Eastern'
var time = '11:00'

var s = moment.tz(zone).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' + time;
var m = moment.tz(s, zone);
var result = m.format();
```

(this assumes your input `time` value is in `HH:mm` format)

Comment: Ha! A great workaround +1 ! But the bug you were referring to was not what bothered me. Check my answer. And afaik if you do new Date('11:00) it will throw an exception, so I'm not sure whether the moment guys will implement that. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Your answer assumes you know what the date is in the target time zone.  If you took that date from your `getTodaysDate` function, your basing on the *local* time zone - which may or may not be the same date as the target's depending on when you call it. "today" is not the same calendar date for everyone on the planet.